# How to use a matrix polynomial to approximate the inverse of a matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

I'm currently working on a problem and it requires me to find the inverse of a matrix by a matrix polynomial:

Assume that $A$ is nonsingular, so how to find the $m$-th order polynomial $p_m(t)$ such that $\|I_n - Ap_m(A)\|_F$ achieves its minimization. Here, $I_n$ denotes the identity matrix. That is, how to use a matrix polynomial to approximate the inverse of a matrix? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: For general $m$ I would just consider the Taylor series of $1/x^2$ truncated at the m-th term.